# Remove border of a framebox

Tags: framed, colorbox

I would like to insert an inline box. I have tried this:

```
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}

\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
 \framebox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\colorbox{shadecolor}{\hspace{1cm}}} }
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to remove the black line of the border around the frame?

Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}` within a TeX group, i.e. `{...}`, this will set the rule width to 0pt and no rule is drawn.

Or ... use `\colorbox{shadecolor}{...}` only.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,.8,.3}

\begin{document}
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
  \framebox{\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}\colorbox{shadecolor}{Foo}}%
}%
\end{document}
```