# lineno inside a minipage

Tags: minipage, lineno

I need to number every line (or by multiple of 2 or 5) of the Greek text. The problem is... lineno is not working inside a minipage.

Before you ask: I am not using Reledmac because One of the two footnote apparatus must stay at the bottom of specific chunks of text and not in the usual place.

BTW I am not dogmatic, so I will buy any other solution!

MWE (minipage is commented)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{fontspec}                               
\setmainfont[]{Times New Roman}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@greeklinenumber}{\resetlinenumber[1]}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname englishlinenumber*\endcsname{\resetlinenumber[1]}
\expandafter\let\csname englishlinenumber\endcsname\@greeklinenumber
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Something before the minipage \\

%\begin{minipage}
\begin{linenumbers}
\begin{verse}
Διὰ τοὺς πτωχοὺς τοῦ λαοῦ σου, διὰ τὴν χήραν καὶ τόν ὀρφανόν, διὰ τὸν ξένον καὶ τὸν προσήλυτον,  δι'ἡμᾶς πάντας τοὺς ἐλπιζόντας καὶ ἐπικαλουμένους τὸ ὄνομά σου τὸ ἅγιον· οἱ γὰρ ὀφθαλμοὶ πάντων εἴς σε ἐλπίζουσιν, καὶ σὺ δίδως τὴν τροφὴν αὐτῶν ἐν εὐκαιρίᾳ. Ὁ διδοὺς τροφὴν πάσῃ σαρκί, πλήρωσον χαρᾶς καὶ εὐφροσύνης τὰς καρδίας ἡμῶν, ἵνα πάντοτε πᾶσαν αὐταρκείαν ἔχοντες περισσεύωμεν εἰς πᾶν ἔργον ἀγαθὸν ἐν Χριστῷ τῷ κυρίῳ ἡμῶν. 
\end{verse}
\end{linenumbers}
%\begin{minipage}
\vspace{1em}
Something after the minipage

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `linenumbers` doesn't work in a minipage.

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103163/line-numbering-with-lineno-within-minipage ?

Comment: and if you want to remove the frame border, maybe something like this is possible https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393676/remove-border-of-a-framebox

Comment: Thx! To get rid of the frame I just deleted \fbox and it worked fine